# Return nodes that were deleted successfully

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the following query to delete nodes and the relationships:

```
MATCH (p:Post), (u:User)
WHERE
 p.name IN ["Latest Post"]
 AND u.id = 1
 AND (p)-[:POST_OWNED_BY]->(u)
 DETACH DELETE p
```

If I pass multiple post names, I would like to be able to return the names of the nodes that were successfully deleted.
I use neo4j manager usingExistingOrNewTransaction(session, tx, query) to commit the query.
Any reference or guide on how to return the successfully deleted nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
MATCH (p:Post), (u:User)
WHERE
 p.name IN ["Latest Post"]
 AND u.id = 1
 AND (p)-[:POST_OWNED_BY]->(u)

// make sure you store the p.name
WITH p, p.name AS deletedName

 DETACH DELETE p

// return the name
RETURN deletedName
```